# JAVA Check for multiple strings ending with a regex pattern in a sentence

Tags: java, regex

I have a sentence `jafjaklf domain1-12-123.eng.abc.com amkfg,fmgsklfgm domain2-134-135.eng.abc.com`. I want to replace the words ending with `.eng.abc.com` with "".

I used the regex pattern:

```
\b(.*\.eng\.abc\.com)\b
```

But it matches `" domain1-12-123.eng.abc.com amkfg,fmgsklfgm domain2-134-135.eng.abc.com"`.

Could anyone help me with the pattern

Comment: It's a simple string.replace - why do you need regex ?

Comment: @pd26 Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the "words" you want to match may contain non-word chars. I suggest matching those parts with a `\S`, non-whitespace pattern:

```
\b\S*\.eng\.abc\.com\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AHvozP/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `\S*` - 0+ chars other than whitespace
- `\.eng\.abc\.com` - a literal `.eng.abc.com` substring
- `\b` - end of word.

Do not forget to double the backslashes in the Java string literal.

[Java demo:](http://ideone.com/p0MP1R)

```
String s = "jafjaklf domain1-12-123.eng.abc.com amkfg,fmgsklfgm domain2-134-135.eng.abc.com";
String pat = "\\s*\\b\\S*\\.eng\\.abc\\.com\\b";
String res = s.replaceAll(pat ,"");
System.out.println(res);
// =>  jafjaklf amkfg,fmgsklfgm
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex, you can use [`String.endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)) and [`String.substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

```
String str = "domain1-12-123.eng.abc.com amkfg,fmgsklfgm domain2-134-135.eng.abc.com";
if (str.endsWith(".eng.abc.com")) {
    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 12);
}
System.out.println(str); // domain1-12-123.eng.abc.com amkfg,fmgsklfgm domain2-134-135
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(str.matches(".*com.?$") || str.matches(".*abc.?$") || str.matches(".*eng.?$"))
```

Comment: It is always recommended that you provide a description of your answer and why you think it is correct.  Code-only answers tend to be frowned upon.